# how to make match query on array field more accurate

Tags: elasticsearch

example:

here is a document:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "beef soup",
            "chicken rice"
        ]
    }
}
```

it can be recalled by below query

```
{
    "match": {
        "name": {
            "query": "soup chicken noodle",
            "minimum_should_match": "67%"
        }
    }
}
```

but I only want it to be recalled by keyword `hot beef soup` or `rice chicken hainan`, is there any way except nested or span query to do this, thanks.

my es query is complex, anyone know how to rewrite it by span query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
          ...
      ],
      "must": {
        "dis_max": {
          "queries": [
            {
              "match": {
                "array_field_3": {
                  "boost": 2,
                  "minimum_should_match": "67%",
                  "query": "keyword aa bb"
                }
              }
            },
            ......
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "path_1",
                "query": {
                    "must": {
                      "match": {
                        "array_field_6": {
                          ......
                          "query": "keyword aa bb"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "tie_breaker": 0.15
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match_phrase` but it will only work for entire phrase. if you want to do only keyword match on each element of array then it is not possible without nested or span as mentioned in [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html).

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
> each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
> need to be able to do this then you should use the nested data type
> instead of the object data type.

When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in the same order as when you indexed the document. The `_source` field that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you indexed.

However, arrays are indexed — made searchable — as multi-value fields, which are unordered. At search time you can’t refer to “the first element” or “the last element”.

Comment: Hi @Sagar Patel, thanks for your reply, the performance of nested struct is bad, so I am investigating how to use span query. My es query is very complex, I added a example in the question, could you please check the question again, thanks

Comment: @user18371782 in above question, where you want to add span query ? for all array field or just where you mentioned dot line.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `match_phrase` query：

```
POST index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "text": {
        "query": "chicken soup"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my description is not clear, I modified it now. could you please check again, thanks.